# Invalid Session Flow

Tags: perl, session

I am trying to submit a form by PERL. I have managed to submit the form, but I am getting an HTML page showing "Invalid Session Flow" after the form submission. If I submit from a browser, the new page contains another form.

I couldn't find the reason why that message could come. Is it possible to troubleshoot if I don't have any access on the server side? Or it has to be checked from server side?

**My Code:**

```
my $url = "https://MY_URL";
my $Browser = new LWP::UserAgent();
$Browser->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0,SSL_verify_mode => 0x00);
my $page = $Browser->get($url);
my $content = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($page->decoded_content) or die $!;
my $match = $content->find_by_attribute('name' => 'token');
my $token = $match->attr('value');
chomp($token);
my %fileds = ("DATA" => "STD111","token" => $token);
my $Page = $Browser->request(POST $url,\%fileds);
if ($Page->is_success){ 
    print $Page->status_line."\n";
    print $Page->content."\n";
}else{
    print $Page->status_line."\n";
    print $Page->message;
}
```

Below is the page sources viewed from FireFox

**Initial Page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/">             
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="5f75b4fb68ed">
        <input name="stdname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">                    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The output I am getting:**

```
200 OK
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="/">
        ERROR: Invalid session flow<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Relogin">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Actual Landing page when submitted via any browser:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="5f75b4fb68ed">
        <input type="password" name="stdpass">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For processing forms, I suggest using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the browser is sending other headers that your LWP program is omitting. When faced by a situation like this, I find the best approach is to use browser plugin I like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for Firefox) that traces the actual HTTP transaction and then change my program to get as close to that as possible.